# How to get reverse relationship object django annotate with subquery?

Tags: django, django-models

It's not a good structure, but it's an example

This is my sample model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Borrower(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class OwnerCard(models.Model):
    certification_date = models.DateField()

class Owner(models.Model):
    owner_card = models.ForeignKey(OwnerCard, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to use reverse relationship to get the object of the Borrower and Owner from the Book Model

Like this

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

Books = Book.objects.all().annotate(
            borrower=Subquery(Borrower.objects.get(user=OuterRef('user'))),
            owner=Subquery(Owner.objects.get(user=OuterRef('user')))
        )
```

Or

```
Books = Book.objects.all().annotate(
            borrower=Subquery(Borrower.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user')).first()),
            owner=Subquery(Owner.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user')).first())
        )
```

and I want use

```
print(Books[0].brrower.name)
>>> brrower's name

print(Books[0].owner.owner_card.certification_date)
>>> certification date
```

But, it's not working.

don't have to use annotate or subquery. Is there a way to implement it this way?

Comment: Just to confirm, you just want the first owner or borrower to be annotated to the book?

Comment: Is it possible to put a single object or a queryset in both cases?